# How to use Array functions inside my own Array prototype function?

Tags: javascript

My first attempt to write an array prototype function.

The original issue is this,

1. array is [2, 0, 1, 3]
2. return 30102, basically reverse the array to be [3, 1, 0, 2]
3. then 3*1000000 + 1 *10000 + 0*100 + 2

So i want to implement an array function to do this

```
Array.prototype.blobArray2Int
    = Array.prototype.blobArray2Int || function() {

    //Array.prototype.reverse();
    Array.prototype = Array.prototype.reverse();
    cnt = Array.prototype.reduce(function(total, num) {
                                return total*100 + num;
                            });
    return cnt;
}
```

The problem is, when i really uses it, the Array inside the implement becomes empty, (i did print the array when i use the blobArray2Int() method).

How to fix it please ? Thanks !

Comment: Well, you definitely don't want to assign the prototype to the result of `reverse`. Have you tried using `this`? `this.reduce(function(...`

Comment: Mike, it's working, :) please post your comments again as reply, so i can accept it, thanks so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to your array as `this` instead of `Array.prototype`. So your code should look more like this:

```js
var a = new Array(2, 0, 1, 3);

Array.prototype.blobArray2Int = Array.prototype.blobArray2Int || function() {
  return this.reduceRight(function(total, num) {
    return total * 100 + num;
  });
};

document.write(a.blobArray2Int());
```